# Alternative to Inner Classes in C++

Tags: c++

Let's say I am writing a "Device Tree Blob" for the bcm2835 RPi chip but in C++ files, rather then `.dts` files.  The intent is to practice C++ and OS concepts.

I would like to be able to encapsulate not just register addresses, but functions which access those, and expose only top level uses as API functions.

In `C++` this could be inner classes, to one big BCM2835 class like so:

```
//bcm2835.h
class BMC2835 : public ARMCpu
{
public:
    void ACKLedOn(void);
    void ACKLdOff(void);
    void ACKLedBlink(void);

    // I2C write to device (this would be called by the device driver)
    // It would ensure that I2C is setup, etc, etc
    void I2C_Device_Write(I2C_Device* device, uint8_t* buffer);
private:

    // Physical addresses for various peripheral register sets
    /// Base Physical Address of the BCM 2835 peripheral registers
    const uint32_t BCM2835_PERI_BASE       = 0x20000000;

    class GPIO()
    {
    private:
       /// Base Physical Address of the Pads registers
       const uint32_t BCM2835_GPIO_PADS    = (BCM2835_PERI_BASE + 0x100000)

       /// Sets the Function Select register for the given pin, which configures
       /// the pin as Input, Output or one of the 6 alternate functions.
       void bcm2835_gpio_fsel(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode);
    }

    class I2C()
    {
       private:
           const uint32_t BCM2835_CORE_CLK_HZ    = 250000000  ;///< 250 MHz
           // Register masks for BSC_C
           const uint32_t BCM2835_BSC_C_I2CEN    = 0x00008000;///< I2C Enable, 0 = disabled, 1 = enabled
           const uint32_t BCM2835_BSC_C_INTR     = 0x00000400;///< Interrupt on RX
           const uint32_t BCM2835_BSC_C_INTT     = 0x00000200;///< Interrupt on TX
           void bcm2835_i2c_begin(void);
           void bcm2835_i2c_write(uint8_t address, uint8* pbuffer);
    }
}
```

And then I can also have a class for the BCM2837 which is 64-bit and handles the LED very differently for example.

```
//bcm2837.h
class BCM2837 : public ARMCpu
{
    public:
        // LED is now a very different Implementation with Mailbox
        // but exposed to Kernel as API
        void ACKLedOn(void);
        void ACKLdOff(void);
        void ACKLedBlink(void);
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am sure there many problems with this approach.  The one that seems to bother me the most is the length of the single class after you include things like `SPI`, `UART`, etc, etc.

Even if the `ARMCpu` is well desigend and 100% virtual (which I would rather avoid in embedded), each CPU class will still be rather lengthy and difficult to read and maintain.

Is there a way to achieve this type of private level access in C++ which is easier?

Comment: Wow, this board supports C++ ?

Comment: That's funny! Yes?

Comment: Haha, I am not joking. Because I thought most of the boards only support C only ... thanks for your reply.

Comment: I thought it was a joke about C vs C++ for embedded.  In the end, it's just binary format.  As long as the `bootloader` can find that binary, then it doesn't matter how you write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put each chip in its own .cpp file, and declare all those private, internal things within that file (and not in the header).  You can wrap them in anonymous namespace to keep them from being exposed to the linker.

Comment: I like that alot! Thanks!